# 'INTERVAL' is not a recognized ODBC date/time extension option

Tags: sql-server, datatypes, errors, odbc, interval

[According to this docs on Interval Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/interval-literals?view=sql-server-2017), this should be a valid `INTERVAL`,

```
SELECT {INTERVAL '326' YEAR(4)};
```

But when I try that on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dc850ff30ae5e9877f51942b74ef287b), I get,

```
Msg 155 Level 15 State 1 Line 1
'INTERVAL' is not a recognized ODBC date/time extension option.
```

Is that error a fault of dbfiddle, SQL Server, or the ODBC transport layer not knowing how to textify a interval -- I tried adding it to a date, hoping that would produce a date but alas same error?

If I try it without the `{}`, I get

```
Msg 102 Level 15 State 1 Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'YEAR'.
```

[image: Interval Literals]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a dbfiddle isn't using ODBC. The "'INTERVAL' is not a recognized" error will be returned by SqlClient.

SqlClient looks like it supports ODBC escape sequences that have corresponding SQL Server data types but I can't find this behavior documented. The error occurs because there is currently no `INTERVAL` type in Microsoft SQL Server.