# Is Microsoft SQL Server 2016 fully ANSI SQL-92 compliant?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-standard

I am trying to find a compliance confirmation for MS SQL 2016 - if it is fully compliant with ANSI SQL-92 starndard.

I found this article on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/sql-92-compliance?view=sql-server-2016) which states it is not, but it refers to ODBC driver and Microsoft Jet engine - not sure if this is exactly the same thing, shouldn't it also relate to T-SQL?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't believe that any version of any database platform on earth is fully compliant with any version of the standard. This is probably why you're not finding any claims of 100% compliance...

You can find some promising starting points over on Stack Overflow in the following Q & A: **[Database Engines and ANSI SQL Compliance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3602617/1820861)**

Many references linked from there are not maintained because database platforms are evolving all the time and this would be many full-time jobs to stay on top of it all. Basically:

- no database platform is 100% compliant, but several come close
- platforms have proprietary additions *on top of* the standard, so your definition of "fully compliant" may vary from someone else's

Answer (score 2):

## No (with examples)

From like the very first page,

> `<concatenation operator>` is an operator, `||`, that returns the character string made by joining its character string operands in the order given.

[SQL Server uses `+`.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

And as far as I know that's SQL 86.

See also

- [INTERVAL types and SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/210711/2639)
- `CURRENT_DATE` `CURRENT_TIME` `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` `CURRENT_USER`
- hex and bit string literals
- `TABLE`
- `CORRESPONDING BY`
- `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, `TIMESTAMP WITH OUT TIME ZONE`
- `DATE` and `TIME` literals
- `DOMAINS`
- `<set column default clause>` not there, but instead [this thing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/214908/2639)
- `<position expression>`

Answer (score 0):

In fact there is 3 levels of compliance to the ISO SQL Standard :

- entry
- intermediate
- full

Except Ocelot RDBMS that claims to be at the full level of SQL:1999 ISO standard, most of professionnal RDBMS claims to be at the entry level...