# How do I an add a DEFAULT on a column if the table already exists?

Tags: postgresql, alter-table, default-value

I want to add a `DEFAULT` for a timestamp column in PostgreSQL. With SQL Server you use [`ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-default-values-for-columns?view=sql-server-2017)

You can see the example in their docs,

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.doc_exz  
ADD CONSTRAINT col_b_def  
DEFAULT 50 FOR column_b;
```

In my case, I'm trying the same pattern,

```
ALTER TABLE foo
ADD CONSTRAINT column_name
  DEFAULT now() FOR bar;
```

This doesn't work. What is the proper way to add a `DEFAULT` for a column in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL, `DEFAULT` is not a constraint. PostgreSQL follows the spec and implements the `<set column default clause>`. See the [`ALTER TABLE` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) documentation for more details. Your command should look like this:

```
ALTER TABLE foo
  ALTER COLUMN column_name
  SET DEFAULT now();
```